# sending GCLID with gtag script to submit offline events-conversions

Tags: gtag.js

I am trying to pass offline conversions from our home made CRM to Google Ads.

Prerequisites:

- when the user clicks on an add, we save the GLID in our Database.
- Event/Conversion is already created in the Google Ads management interface. Let’s call this conversion “test_conversion”
- The event type is “webpage” -  by this I mean that our sales manager visits this web-page to confirm that “deal has been closed”

Is it possible to use gtag  script to pass the gclid with the following format

```
gtag('event', 'test_conversion', {

  'send_to': 'YOUR_AW_CONVERSION_ID/YOUR_AW_CONVERSION_LABEL',

  'value': 1.0,

  'gclid': 'YOUR_GCLID_VALUE' // Include the actual GCLID value here
```

Or is there any other way to push the fact of the event to the google ads platform with our saved GCLID with the help of GTAG script?

I tried to include the GCLID as I described above, but the event doesn't seem to be reaching Google Ads network (though, server response is 2** OK (I think it was 204 OK). I mean that in Google Analytics/Google Ads I can see the event/conversion name that I previously created, but it shows zero clicks, though, the even has been sent by our web-site.